# Problem importing TensorFlow 2 in Python (running on WSL in Windows)

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, tensorflow2.0

Problem: I followed Microsoft's instruction in order to properly install and run TensorFlow 2 in WSL with GPU acceleration, using DirectML ([here's the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ai/directml/gpu-tensorflow-plugin)).

Following the installation, when I try and import tensorflow in Python I get the following output:

```
>>> import tensorflow 
                                                                                               
2022-11-22 15:52:33.090032: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193]
This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)
to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA                                                                                                               

To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                       
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                                                                                    
File "/home/pietro/miniconda3/envs/testing/lib/python3.9/site-package
/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 440, in <module>   
_ll.load_library(_plugin_dir)                                                                                        
File "/home/pietro/miniconda3/envs/testing/lib/python3.9/site-package
/tensorflow/python/framework/load_library.py", line 151, in load_library                                                                                                   
py_tf.TF_LoadLibrary(lib)                                                                                          
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: /home/pietro
/miniconda3/envs/testing/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow-plugin
/libtfdml_plugin.so: undefined symbol:_ZN10tensorflow8internal15LogMessageFatalD1Ev, version tensorflow
```

I tried instead to follow the instructions for TensorFlow 1 and PyTorch (just in case something was wrong with my machine) and they both work perfectly, so I assume this issue only involves TensorFlow 2 somehow.

Did anyone encounter the same problem?
Thanks to everybody in advance :)
Pietro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same problem, and downgrading TensorFlow from 2.11 fixed it. First remove the existing version:

```
pip uninstall tensorflow-cpu
```

Then re-install, this time with 2.10.0:

```
pip install tensorflow-cpu==2.10.0
```

After that, try importing it in Python. You should see something like the following (apologies for the messy output):

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
2022-11-28 22:41:21.693757: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 AVX512F AVX512_VNNI FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-11-28 22:41:21.806150: I tensorflow/core/util/util.cc:169] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
2022-11-28 22:41:22.982148: I tensorflow/c/logging.cc:34] Successfully opened dynamic library libdirectml.d6f03b303ac3c4f2eeb8ca631688c9757b361310.so
2022-11-28 22:41:22.982289: I tensorflow/c/logging.cc:34] Successfully opened dynamic library libdxcore.so
2022-11-28 22:41:22.996385: I tensorflow/c/logging.cc:34] Successfully opened dynamic library libd3d12.so
2022-11-28 22:41:27.615851: I tensorflow/c/logging.cc:34] DirectML device enumeration: found 1 compatible adapters.
```

You can test that it works by adding two tensors. Running a command like the following:

```
print(tf.add([1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]))
```

And somewhere in the output, you should be able to verify that DirectML has found your GPU:

```
2022-11-28 22:43:42.632447: I tensorflow/c/logging.cc:34] DirectML: creating device on adapter 0 (NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080)
```

Hope this helps!